# "No route matches.." error when trying to delete item from cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, e-commerce

I have a shopping cart of products (called "line_items"), and I'm trying to add a button to decrease the amount of something from the cart:

```
3x  Coke $2.97  (-)
```

Here's the code for the "(-)" portion:

```
<%= button_to '(-)',  line_item, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', 
:method => :destroy, :product_id => line_item.product_id %>
```

My line_item.destroy function is pretty simple, it just decrements the quantity and then redirects back to the homepage.  In testing, when I try to click the button, I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/line_items/61")
```

So it appears that the system is trying to visit the URL for the line_item, instead of following the destroy function I've set up in the controller it like I thought it would.  Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: `:method` is the HTTP verb and it should be `:delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:method` is the HTTP verb and it should be `:delete` and not `:destroy`

Comment: Interesting.. so :method => delete calls line_item.destroy?  How does it make the jump?

Comment: It is because you have defined it as a resource in `routes.rb` file. Resources define 7 routes for you. You can call `rake routes` to see all the routes defined in your application. See [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)